# How to pass 2-dimensional char array to class c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

EDIT I believe the problem is in the main, the course doesnt get passed like its suppossed to. If i find the mistake I will post the solution

EDIT I forgot to inform you where I get the error
I always get it after I enter the 0 (which signals the end of input)

I just want to make an array of strings(char arrays, yes i know about std::string) and pass it to the constructor, but i keep getting memory access errors
EDIT:

```
class person {
  int ID;
  char* pname;
  char* course[30];
public:
  person(){}
  person(int ID, char *pname, char* course[30]){
    if(ID<=999999 && ID>0){
        this->ID=ID;
        pname=new char[256];
        strcpy(this->pname,pname); //this works
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            this->course[i]=new char[256];
            strcpy(this->course[i],course[i]); //but this doesnt
            }
    }
    else printf("\nFehler bei der ID eingabe!\n\n");
}
~person(){
    delete []pname;
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        delete[] course[i];
    delete[] course;
}
};
```

so this is my class and this is the part where I use it:

```
int main(){
  person* array[1000];
  //...
 char temp[256];
 char* course[30];
 int h=0;
 while(i<30&&*temp!='0'){
    fgets(temp,256,stdin);
    if(*temp!='0'){
         while(temp[h]!='\n') h++; //have to do this because i have to  delete the \n from cin
        temp[h]='\0';
        h=0;
        strcpy(course[i],temp);
        //course[i]=temp[i];
        }
    else break;
    i++;
}
while(i<30){
    course[i]=NULL;i++;}
array[pos]=new person(ID,name,course); //pos is a int value which i calculate elsewhere in the code
```

it works perfectly fine but the char* array course just wont work, even though the char* name is used just like this.
Im new to stackoveroflow, I hope I didnt go too overboard with the code :S

Comment: An array is just a pointer.  So you're looking for `char**`

Comment: Please could you make your code readable so it can be read? are you lazy or is your space bar key stuck? or is it that you don't want to waste space on your hard drive?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: It's not.

Comment: Sure sure, it's technically more than a pointer.  But it's a useful rule of thumb that helps you in this situation.

Comment: sorry i really tried to make it short and readable but it seems like it didnt work, will try to further shorten it

Comment: Why are you doing this: while(i<30){course[i]=NULL;i++;}.

Comment: You could do `person( ..., char* (*course)[30])` and access the elements like this `(* course)[i] = ...`. And pass it like this `person(..., &course);`.

Comment: @haripkannan if course isnt filled i just want to fill in the rest will NULL pointers

Comment: @alk will try it right now

Comment: doesnt work so far but i keep changing it so we'll see

Comment: I would avoid to have same name for arguments and members... as you miss several `this->` to use the correct variables.

Comment: As you know about `std::string`, use it. If you can't use it, write your own class `MyString` to isolate this problematic. Then do the same with `std::vector` (dynamic array).

Comment: thanks for the replies Im changing most of the things you point out, but at the moment Im on my tablet so no fancy visual studio only the good old notepad ++ and it takes a while to compile -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 3**
In your main function put

```
 for(int j=0;j<30;j++)
    course[j] = new char[256];
 i=0;
```

and make sure that i of your while loop is initialized with 0
After this your first while works for me
For second while, I dont understand why you have made all the inputs that you took(course[i]) to null, I guess you should remove that while.

and now when I try

```
char name[50];
strcpy(name,"naruto");
person *xyz = new person(0,name,course);
```

**SUCCESS**

**UPDATE 2**
To be More Accurate

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        strcpy(this->course[i],course[i]); //but this doesnt
        //this->course[i]=course[i];
```

Should have been

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
{
        this->course[i]=new char[256]; //but this should fix it
        strcpy(this->course[i],course[i]); 
        //this->course[i]=course[i];
}
```

The new arrays that you created before were for course[i] and not for this->course[i]

**In fact by doing**

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
            course[i]=new char[256];
```

You are basically overwriting the input course[30] that you just received with blank strings, resulting in a logical error. (delete this part of your code)

**Old Post**
before you copy from temp to course[i] all you have to do is

```
course[i] = new char[MAX_SIZE_OF_YOUR_STRING];
```

(also in your class and wherever you are dealing with array of pointers)

**Example**
This will crash

```
int main()
{
    char* course[30];
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {

        cin>>course[i];
    }
}
```

But this will not

```
int main()
{
    char* course[30];
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        course[i] = new char[256];
        cin>>course[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is not having problem taking input in main. Having allocated temp and doing strcpy into course[i] will take care of the problem that you are pointing out (even though your solution is more elegant).

Comment: @Jarod42 thats what op requires

Comment: @haripkannan, the part where OP says it doesen't work, missed creating new array for array of that class

Comment: OP doesn't have buffer overflow when he read "big" input (he has one when he try to replace `\n` by `\0`...).

Comment: @Jarod42, note the difference between his code that works and that doesent.The "buffer overflow" its not at all related to 256. It is just because he is copying into location(pointer) that is not even initialized (garbage value I guess..). I have also updated my post.

Comment: I corrected the `this->` and now it looks like this: `for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    
    this->course[i]=new char[256];
    strcpy(this->course[i],course[i]);
   
   }` but I still get the same error

Comment: @SuperKeksmann Remove this from your `code` too `for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
            course[i]=new char[256]; ` as you are overwriting the input course[30] that you just received with blank strings, resulting in a logical error.

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo: I don't say that you don't solve some OP's problems, just that you keep one in shown code.

Comment: I updatet it in my post and in my code but Im still getting the error

Comment: @SuperKeksmann I had no clue that you had issues in your main function too. I have updated my post.